# what does ?. mean in Angular

Tags: angular6

I saw this code. What does `?.` mean? I tried to google it but couldn't find anything

```
<div *ngIf="primaryEmail.errors?.email">
     Primary Email not valid.
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. So I guess, using a `?` after a variable creates a sort of `null`/`undefined `check

Comment: Yes indeed,  It checks whether the variable is null or undefined so that our template won't try to select a property of something falsy.